# how to debug variable in function inside model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am using Cakephp 2.3. 
In my model, I have a function to check for duplicates. I want to check the number of duplicates and report it to the user. However, the variable I set in the function seems to be not available to me in the view.

Model:
    class Student extends AppModel {

```
public $validate = array(
'promotion_code' => array(
'rule' => array('limitDuplicates', 1),
'message' =>  "there are x duplicates" )
);

public function limitDuplicates($check, $limit) {
$existing_promo_count = $this->find('count', array(
'conditions' => $check,
'recursive' => -1
)); 
$this->set('results', $existing_promo_count);
return $existing_promo_count < $limit;
}
}
```

In the view

```
debug("duplicate count is ". $results);
```

results in

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: results
```

Please advice how to display a variable I set in a function in the model to be available to the error message in the View.

Thanks.

Comment: The code in the question calls `Model::set` on the model instance - which does not pass values to the view. `Controller::set` does that.

Answer (score 0):

Where in your `Controller` are you calling this function?

Since the function in the Model is returning a value, you would have to call the function in your Controller by passing in `$check` and `$limit` and then `set` the returned value, so your View has access to it.

Controller:

`$this->set('result', $this->Model->limitDuplicates($check, $limit));`

Your View should now have access to the result variable, assuming the Model, View and Controller are all related correctly. Also, get rid of the `set` statement in your Model.

Comment: hi Chronix3, thanks. I am not calling the function in the Controller. It is being called from the data validation in the Model itself. But I want to show the number of duplicates to the user, and also debug this value from within the function in the model.